# How to supress a Shiny observeEvent firing in a lapply

Tags: r, dplyr, shiny, tidyverse

I am looking for a little assistance on an overly sensitive R Shiny reactiveValues object please.  Thanks in advance.

I am aiming to develop a simple form that returns 3 Shiny fluidrows via calls on renderUI in an lapply. Each row has two buttons and a value which starts at 0. The value should increment or decrease by 1 by respectively clicking the “plus” or “minus” buttons.

When either button is clicked though the observeEvent keeps firing, as can be seen with the call to print the updated value. I placed an isolate up front but that negates the front-end value from updating.

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)

ui <- fluidPage(
  uiOutput('oupt_q11')
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  tbl_vals <- reactiveValues(
    pos_1    = 0
    , pos_2  = 0
    , pos_3  = 0
  )  
  
  output$oupt_q11 <- renderUI({
    
    lapply(seq_along(1:3), function(x){
      
      # tbl_vals_x <- isolate(as.character(tbl_vals[[paste0('pos_', x)]]))
      tbl_vals_x <- as.character(tbl_vals[[paste0('pos_', x)]])
      
      hold_rtrn <- fluidRow(
        column(12,
               style = 'background-color: #b8c2d1'
               , column(3, actionButton(paste0('btn_less_', x), label = ' - '))
               , column(3, tbl_vals_x)
               , column(3, actionButton(paste0('btn_more_', x), label = ' + '))
        ))
      
      observeEvent(input[[paste0('btn_less_', x)]], {
        
        pass_value <- as.numeric(tbl_vals[[paste0('pos_', x)]])
        tbl_vals[[paste0('pos_', x)]] <- pass_value - 1
        print(tbl_vals[[paste0('pos_', x)]])
        
      })
      
      observeEvent(input[[paste0('btn_more_', x)]], {
        
        pass_value <- as.numeric(tbl_vals[[paste0('pos_', x)]])
        tbl_vals[[paste0('pos_', x)]] <- pass_value + 1
        print(tbl_vals[[paste0('pos_', x)]])
        
      })
      return(hold_rtrn)
    })
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Why are the observeEvents inside this function? They should be in the main server function usually. The renderUI should just contain the code that generates the UI output for that item, it doesn't have server functionality

Comment: My thinking was that the iterator ‘x’ could be used in input[[paste0('btn_more_', x)]] with observeevent this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put the `observeEvent()` outside the `renderUI`.  It works.  Try this.

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)

ui <- fluidPage(
  uiOutput('oupt_q11')
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  tbl_vals <- reactiveValues(
    pos_1    = 0
    , pos_2  = 0
    , pos_3  = 0
  )  
  
  output$oupt_q11 <- renderUI({
    hold_rtrn <- list()
    
    lapply(seq_along(1:3), function(x){
      #tbl_vals_x <- as.character(tbl_vals[[paste0('pos_', x)]])
      
      hold_rtrn[[x]] <<- fluidRow(
        column(12,
               style = 'background-color: #b8c2d1'
               , column(3, actionButton(paste0('btn_less_', x), label = ' - '))
               , column(3, as.character(tbl_vals[[paste0('pos_', x)]]))
               , column(3, actionButton(paste0('btn_more_', x), label = ' + '))
        ))
      
    })
    hold_rtrn
  })
  
  lapply(1:3, function(x) {
    observeEvent(input[[paste0('btn_less_', x)]], {
      pass_value <- as.numeric(tbl_vals[[paste0('pos_', x)]])
      tbl_vals[[paste0('pos_', x)]] <- pass_value - 1
      print(tbl_vals[[paste0('pos_', x)]])
      
    })
    
    observeEvent(input[[paste0('btn_more_', x)]], {
      pass_value <- as.numeric(tbl_vals[[paste0('pos_', x)]])
      tbl_vals[[paste0('pos_', x)]] <- pass_value + 1
      print(tbl_vals[[paste0('pos_', x)]])
      
    })
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```